# Construction by side identification analogous to flat torus

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I know that the flat torus and the Kleinian bottle result from identication of opposite sides of a square given some orientation. I am interested in following cases.
[image]

$A$ becomes in my understanding two cones which are glued together on their base and is, therefore, homeomorphic to a sphere. I am completely lost regarding $B$ and $C$. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: Start by proving the $B$ and $C$ are homeomorphic. Then think about the classification theorem of surfaces using normal forms. What does it tell you in this case?

Comment: By this page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon they are projective planes, right?

Comment: No, but you are very close.

Comment: $C$ is a Klein Bottle? All arrows leading in a cercle (compared to the 4th picture of the Wikipedia article.). And homeomorphism follows from the fact that flipping two arrows of identifiable edges does not change the the resulting surface after identification.

Comment: Yes, but you should learn how to prove these things yourself w/o Wikipedia.

Comment: Definitely, but for building a first understanding it is quite efficient.